Login failed for user "sa" on SSMS with Docker container
I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server Docker container via SQL Server Management Studio, but it doesn't work. When I attempt to connect, I get this error:

Login failed for user 'sa'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

I run the container with this command:
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password" 
           -p 1433:1433 --name=bd_sql_server 
           -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

Here is the info I provided in the "Connect to server" window in SSMS:
"Connect to server" window in SSMS
and the container running in Docker Desktop:
Container running in Docker Desktop
I made sure that the password was the same I specified.
I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me?
Thanks.

Rather than 127.0.0.1, have you tried .?

What shell were you using when you executed the docker run command? It would probably work OK from a Command Prompt or PowerShell, but in a bash-like shell the ! character has special significance for accessing the command history.

@ThomA Do you mean typing ".,1433" instead of "127.0.0.1,1433"?

@AlwaysLearning I used the basic command prompt on Windows, the one you open by typing cmd in the search bar.

You don't need the port, 1433 is the default, @MathisMahaux .

@ryanwebjackson SQL Server doesn't use HTTP, so that's not going to work

@MathisMahaux
hi Mathis, Charlie here
probably you have a windows desktop version of MSSQL and you forgot to stop the local service before connecting to the docker version.
good Luck !

Test that the SQL server is assecible within container
docker exec -it bd_sql_server /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P yourStrong(!)Password

if you can connect to the SQL command line , than there is the problem with the MSSQL configuration and network setting
